Jaxb binding attribute to string without adapter
Is it possible to have a binding to a string without an adapter?
I have a 3rd party schema with an attribute with the wrong type (date) and in an external file binding I transform it to string so the class is generated with the correct type. The "problem" is that it does so through a new class "Adapter1" which is very trivial and I prefer it not to be generated.
The attribute is as:
      <xs:attribute  type="xs:date" name="curso" use="required">
      </xs:attribute>

And the current binding is:
<jxb:bindings 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings 
            schemaLocation="file.xsd" 
            node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='exportacion_horarios']//xs:attribute[@name='curso']" >
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType >
                    <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

The adapter class is:
package com.penalara.ghc_importar_exportar.modelo.personalizados.itaca3.exportacion;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, String>
{


    public String unmarshal(String value) {
        return new String(value);
    }

    public String marshal(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.toString();
    }

}

Maybe something like telling "xjc" to use the internal default adapter for string-to-string.

You can do it by not using jxb:javaType and putting the name directly in the jxb:baseType.
<jxb:bindings 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings 
            schemaLocation="file.xsd" 
            node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='exportacion_horarios']//xs:attribute[@name='curso']" >
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType name="java.lang.String"/>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>


This way it doesn't generate an adapter and uses Java String.

You can change the <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" /> instruction with XJC's one, which allow defining the adapter parameter and avoid these weird adapter class.
This would give something like the following binding file :
<jxb:bindings 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jxb:bindings 
            schemaLocation="file.xsd" 
            node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='exportacion_horarios']//xs:attribute[@name='curso']" >
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType >
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String"  adapter="com.penalara.ghc_importar_exportar.modelo.ToStringAdapter" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

Note that com.penalara.ghc_importar_exportar.modelo.ToStringAdapter stated here is a internal class of yours which will extend XmlAdapter<String, String>

But still, you need an adapter. jxb:javatype also has a similar option with parseMethod and printMethod. But I want to use the internal conversion jaxb so no code is necessary from my project. Is there an already existing class you can point to in "adapter"?

The jxb:javaType will always generate adapter even if providing the methods. The advantage of xjc:javaType alternative is that you can point at any existing class to avoid generating the adapter. Found com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.RuntimeUtil.ToStringAdapter but unmarshal is exception throwing so my best bet is for you to create the empty XmlAdapter needed
